# How to get Unicode properties of a character?

Tags: javascript, python

In Python I'd use the `unicodedata` package to identify punctuation characters at the start of strings:

```
import unicodedata as UD

_string = '¿para qué?'
if UD.category(_string[0]).startswith('P'):
    print('Punctuation at beginning of string.')
```

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: @close voters: The question asks for an equivalent of this functionality, but it's not asking for library recommendations. If this functionality doesn't exist in JS and needs external packages, write an answer that states that. No part of this question is off-topic.

Comment: Totally valid question. I'm almost tempted to start a bounty on it right away, but cannot because it's still fresh at this point. I realise as a js dev, I have so little experience with unicode problems. Would love to see more input.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no built-in way to get this information.

A cursory search shows that a popular package for it is [unicode-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unicode-properties), whose build-script compiles a JSON database using a package called [codepoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codepoints).

The codepoints package contains several large text files that seem to be from the Unicode Character Database at https://unicode.org/ucd/.

From this I would conclude that the only way to get the information in JS is via this external source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.

```js
console.log("!abc".match(/^\p{Punctuation}/u));

// more:
console.log("A".match(/\p{Lowercase_Letter}/u));
console.log("\u{1f354}".match(/\p{Emoji_Presentation}/u));
console.log("中".match(/\p{Script=Han}/u));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Christoph! Exactly what I was looking for. 
After installing unicode-properties with npm,

```
var unicode = require('unicode-properties')
unicode.getCategory('¿para qué?'.charCodeAt())
```

This returns 'Po', which tells me I've got at punctuation character.

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
!!str.match(/^[.,:!?]/)
```

This will tell you if your string starts with any of the characters within [].

Comment: Man, I think you're confusing `java` with `javascript`

Comment: There are a lot of punctuation characters in Unicode besides these. (All the ones categorized as Pc, Pd, Pi, Pf, Ps, Pe, or Po, apparently 598 in total currently https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html)

Comment: Plus, `\p{Punct}` only matches US-ASCII punctuations, which is one of ```!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~```

Comment: I also discovered XRegExp (http://xregexp.com). With this JavaScript library I can match all punctuation with the pattern:

    var re = new XRegExp('\\p{Punctuation}');